# Running .NET 4 application with Mono

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, mono

I'm trying to run a .NET exe on a Ubuntu machine (I installed the package `mono-complete`), so far with no luck. The application is compiled with Visual C# Express 2010 under .NET 4 (Client Profile).

I try executing the program with the following command:

```
mono application.exe
```

However, I get the following error:

> WARNING: The runtime version supported
>   by this application is unavailable.
>   Using default runtime: v1.1.4322
>
> ** (application.exe:5586): WARNING **: Missing method
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(bool)
>   in assembly
>   /usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Windows.Forms/1.0.5000.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll,
>   referenced in assembly
>   /media/disk/application.exe
>
> Unhandled Exception:
>   System.MissingMethodException: Method
>   not found:
>   'System.Windows.Forms.Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault'.

It's suppose to be using .NET 4, not 1, but I don't know how to set it. I tried

```
mono --runtime=4.0.30319.1 application.exe
```

But that didn't work either.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which version of Mono do you have? I believe .NET 4.0 requires 2.8

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Sounds like you're experiencing this bug:

[My Doc's Got No Nodes: .net 4 Client Profile on Mono 2.8](http://nonodes.spunow.co.uk/2010/11/net-4-client-profile-on-mono-28.html)

That is assuming you installed > Mono 2.8 (which was the first release to support .NET 4.0). If not, you should install a more recent Mono package.

The other thing to keep in mind is that Mono doesn't support the entirety of WinForms. Unless you developed your application with Mono in mind, there's a good chance you'll find that something you used isn't supported.

Comment: I [upgraded Mono](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5304/upgrading-to-latest-stable-mono), but now I have more things to deal with. Thanks for your assistance with this particular issue!

Comment: @Tim Cooper - No problem! Glad I could help.

Comment: You are right. I have upgrade it to 2.11 and it seems everything working

Answer (score 3):

I suspect the exception is because the method System.Windows.Forms.Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault hasn't been implemented.  Have you ran the tool through the [Mono Migration Analyzer (MoMA)](http://www.mono-project.com/MoMA), should help in knowing whether your application is compatible with mono.  From that point you can possibly workaround the problem, maybe even incorporating the missing method in your code.

Comment: There are a couple of errors, but none related to the `SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault` method. They are mostly related to auto complete. I'll try removing them temporarily to see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

Current mono-complete package (even on Ubuntu Natty) uses mono 2.6.7 which doesn't support .NET 4.0 API. You'll have to build newest version of mono, which is the best way to get a chance of using 4.0 API. "[Complete](http://www.mono-project.com/Roadmap)" support of .NET 4.0 is however planned in mono 3.0.

Comment: Mono [2.6+](http://www.mono-project.com/Release_Notes_Mono_2.6) had experimental support for .NET 4 if you configured it when you compiled Mono. I would certainly recommend using the [latest](http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html) version of Mono available if targeting .NET 4.

Answer (score 0):

Install Monodevelop and just right click on the example.csprj that is a C#.NET project in linux and click on Monodevelop.