# Could not load type System.Runtime.Versioning.TargetFrameWorkAttribute from assembly

Tags: c#, json, mono

I am trying to compile a program that uses the library `Newtonsoft.Json.dll` with mono

Compile command

```
gmcs Program.cs etcetera.cs -r:Newtonsoft.Json.dll -r:Argotic.Core.dll
```

Result:

```
Missing method .ctor in assembly Newtonsoft.Json.dll, type System.Runtime.Versioning.TargetFrameworkAttribute
Can't find custom attr constructor image: Newtonsoft.Json.dll mtoken: 0x0a000053
```

And then when trying to run the program (`mono Program.exe`) it throws the error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Runtime.Versioning.TargetFrameworkAttribute' from assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json'.

  at my_program.CJSONStuff.serialize (System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2 obj) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at my_program.TheObjDB.getAllSerialized () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at my_program.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Runtime.Versioning.TargetFrameworkAttribute' from assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json'.

  at my_program.CJSONStuff.serialize (System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2 obj) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at my_program.TheObjDB.getAllSerialized () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at my_program.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

I have never used mono before, and have no idea what's going on.. but maybe this means the DLL can't be used because it hasn't been compiled with mono as well? If that's the case; does this mean I can't use any 3d party DLLs with mono unless I also have the source code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because default mono uses v 2.0 runtime but nuget is using v4.0. its can be resolve by defining runtime parameter on mono:

```
mono --runtime=v4.0.30319 NuGet.exe
```

Source: http://monomvc.wordpress.com/2012/03/06/nuget-on-mono/

Comment: Thanks, that worked fine on windows! On an unrelated note, linux sais 'the runtime version supported by this app is unavailable, using default runtime v1.1.4322' but that looks like a different problem altogether. Will accept answer when I can.

Comment: Have you checked this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5327672/running-net-4-application-with-mono

Comment: Yeah, looks like `apt-get install mono-complete` installed version 2.6.7 where I need at least 2.8 for .net 4.0... looks like I have to install 2.10 from source.. bah. Thanks though!

Comment: Incidentally I wonder why you have to override the runtime used? According to `mono`'s man page you only need to do this when trying run an assembly on different run-time to the one it targeted, perhaps it just falled back on what you had..