# mono-service2 Could not load type 'System.Runtime.Versioning.TargetFrameworkAttribute'

Tags: c#, .net, mono, mono-service

I have written a C# .NET Windows Service with running on Linux using mono in mind.

- The Service targets .NET Framework 4 Client Profile
- I have run Mono Migration Analyzer (MoMA) against the .exe and .dlls, all looks OK.
- .exe built on Windows using VS2010
- Mono JIT compiler version 2.10.8.1 on Ubuntu x64 12.04

After copying the binaries across I run:

```
mono-service2 MyService.exe
```

it returns immediately. Running `ps -a` it does not appear to be running and in `syslog` I see:

```
mono: MyService.exe: Could not load type 'System.Runtime.Versioning.TargetFrameworkAttribute' from assembly 'MyService'.
```

It seems mono does not support the version of .NET I am targeting? What can I do?

Comment: try `mono-service2 --runtime=v4.0.30319 MyService.exe`

Comment: Google "mono targetframeworkattribute" and click on the first hit.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Could not load type System.Runtime.Versioning.TargetFrameWorkAttribute from assembly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11600337/could-not-load-type-system-runtime-versioning-targetframeworkattribute-from-asse)

Comment: @HansPassant difference is I am running `mono-service2` not `mono`, although I see now the argument is accepted even though the man page does not mention it.

Comment: Actually I see now one cannot pass that argument to `mono-service2` at all, it tries to load it as an assembly! So this is definitely not a duplicate - I have updated the title to make that clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out 'mono-service2' maps to /usr/lib/mono/2.0 whereas 'mono-service' maps to /usr/lib/mono/4.5!

So just use `mono-service`:

```
mono-service MyService.exe
```

(Wish they would update the man page).